# Сумма заказа Megento

Tags: cms, magento, themes

как и что прописать, что бы на главной возле количества заказанного товара(это я вывел) выводилась бы еще общая сумма?вписал вот это `<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getSubtotal()) ?>` ,нашел в интернете,а оно выдает,что все по нулям,хотя в корзине есть заказ.

Answer (score 1):

вот правильное решение.мб кому то поможет

```
<?php
                    $totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getTotals(); //Total object
                    $grandtotal = round($totals["grand_total"]->getValue()); //Grandtotal value
                    echo $formattedPrice = Mage::helper('core')->currency($grandtotal , true, false);
                    ?>
```